# Nextflow: Properly chaining process outputs

Tags: nextflow

I have written a pipeline that is composed of three processes. I seem to be misunderstanding how Nextflow passes the outputs from one process to the next or creates a queue of files. I am using a tumor and paired normal sample from SRA ([SRX21185781](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra/SRX21185781%5Baccn%5D)) to prototype this pipeline.

My first process, `trim_QC` works fine and outputs the expected number of trimmed fastqs. However, the next process, `bwa_align` only creates a single bam from one of the two output from the preceding process. My terminal looks like this:

```
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 23.10.1
Launching `../main.nf` [sick_church] DSL2 - revision: beb03cc0c6

[6e/48d4f6] process > trim_QC (SRR25452858_normal)                  [100%] 2 of 2, cached: 2 ✔
[39/1b8cb2] process > bwa_align (SRR25452858_normal)                [100%] 1 of 1, cached: 1 ✔
[5f/e598c1] process > mapping_stats (SRR25452858_normal_sorted.bam) [100%] 1 of 1, cached: 1 ✔
...
```

and when running with `-with-trace` it is even more obvious only one bam file is being processed by the downstream processes:

```
task_id hash    native_id   name    status  exit    submit  duration    realtime    %cpu    peak_rss    peak_vmem   rchar   wchar
2   d3/0bd651   71127   trim_QC (SRR25452863_tumor) CACHED  0   2024-02-07 16:28:37.449 1h 21m 10s  1h 21m 10s  -   -   -   -   -
1   6e/48d4f6   71128   trim_QC (SRR25452858_normal)    CACHED  0   2024-02-07 16:28:37.459 1h 16m 32s  1h 16m 32s  -   -   -   -   -
3   39/1b8cb2   2754    bwa_align (SRR25452858_normal)  CACHED  0   2024-02-08 10:08:46.033 4h 18m 10s  4h 18m 10s  -   -   -   -   -
4   5f/e598c1   9282    mapping_stats (SRR25452858_normal_sorted.bam)   CACHED  0   2024-02-08 14:26:55.823 53.9s   53.8s   -   -   -   -   -
```

I am expecting for the `bwa-align` and `mapping_stats` processes to also be n of 2.

I have tried explicitly designating the `trim_QC.out` as a channel (`Channel.of(trim_QC.out)`) or using an operator to return a queue channel object (i.e., `.collect`, `.collectFile()`, etc.) but this either returns errors or fails.

If I try to visualize the outputs from the `trim_QC` process by adding this to my workflow: `trim_QC.out.trimmed_reads.view{it}`, it does show both file pairs in my terminal, but only the first one is processed by `bwa_align` and subsequent steps. Like so:

```
...
[6e/48d4f6] process > trim_QC (SRR25452858_normal)            [100%] 2 of 2, cached: 2 ✔
[39/1b8cb2] process > bwa_align (SRR25452858_normal)          [100%] 1 of 1, cached: 1 ✔
[5f/e598c1] process > mapping_stats (SRR25452858_normal_so... [100%] 1 of 1, cached: 1 ✔
hello

[SRR25452858_normal, /Users/me/Desktop/fastq2/work/6e/48d4f61cae83ff903abceaadf715e5/SRR25452858_normal_1_val_1.fq.gz, /Users/me/Desktop/fastq2/work/6e/48d4f61cae83ff903abceaadf715e5/SRR25452858_normal_2_val_2.fq.gz]
Analysis complete for SRR25452858_normal_1_val_1.fq.gz
Analysis complete for SRR25452858_normal_2_val_2.fq.gz

[SRR25452863_tumor, /Users/me/Desktop/fastq2/work/d3/0bd6515fcedfc060596b75dd90c28a/SRR25452863_tumor_1_val_1.fq.gz, /Users/me/Desktop/fastq2/work/d3/0bd6515fcedfc060596b75dd90c28a/SRR25452863_tumor_2_val_2.fq.gz]
Analysis complete for SRR25452863_tumor_1_val_1.fq.gz
Analysis complete for SRR25452863_tumor_2_val_2.fq.gz
```

I am unsure if I am misunderstanding what Nextflow is capable of or how channels work. What I am trying to accomplish is trim adapters and QC result, align trimmed reads followed by indexing, and finally calculate mappings statistics. Any advice is appreciated.

Here is my entire script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow
nextflow.enable.dsl = 2

params.fastq = "$projectDir/fastq2/*_{1,2}*"
params.index_dir = "$projectDir/RefGenome/BWAIndex"
params.ref = "hg38.fa"
params.out_dir = "$projectDir/Results"

workflow {

    fastq_ch = Channel.fromFilePairs(params.fastq)
    index_ch = Channel.fromPath(params.index_dir)
    ref_ch = Channel.of(params.ref)

    trim_QC(fastq_ch)
    bwa_align(index_ch, ref_ch, trim_QC.out.trimmed_reads)
    mapping_stats(bwa_align.out.sorted_bam)
}

process trim_QC {
    debug true
    tag "$sample_id"

    publishDir = [
                    [
                        path: { "${params.out_dir}/trimmed/" },
                        mode: 'copy',
                        overwrite: false
                    ],

                    [
                        path: { "${params.out_dir}/stats/" },
                        mode: 'copy',
                        pattern: "*fastqc*",
                        overwrite: false
                    ]
                ]

    input:
    tuple val(sample_id), path(fastq)

    output:
    tuple val("${sample_id}"), path("*_val_1.fq.gz"), path("*_val_2.fq.gz"), emit: trimmed_reads
    path("*fastqc*")

    script:
    def (read1, read2) = fastq
    """
    trim_galore --paired --fastqc ${read1} ${read2}
    """
}

process bwa_align {
    debug true
    tag "$sample_id"

    publishDir "${params.out_dir}/bwa_aligned/", mode: 'copy', overwrite: false

    input:
    path index_dir
    val ref
    tuple val(sample_id), path(read1), path(read2)

    output:
    path("${sample_id}_sorted.bam"), emit: sorted_bam
path("${sample_id}_sorted.bam.bai"), emit: bam_index

    script:
    """
    bwa mem -t 2 ${index_dir}/${ref} ${read1} ${read2} | samtools sort -@2 -o "${sample_id}_sorted.bam" -
samtools index ${sample_id}_sorted.bam > "${sample_id}_sorted.bam.bai"
    """
}

process mapping_stats {
    debug true
    tag "$sorted_bam"

    publishDir "${params.out_dir}/stats/", mode: 'copy', overwrite: false

    input:
    path(sorted_bam)

    output:
    path("${sorted_bam}_mapping_stats.txt")

    script:
    """
    samtools flagstat ${sorted_bam} > "${sorted_bam}_mapping_stats.txt"
    """
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a result of nextflow channel types, [queue- and value-channels](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#channel-types). Nextflow will make fifo combinations of your channels to run `bwa_align` until either or both channel are empty. `index_ch` contains only one item, so once it is used there are no more valid combinations to start new  `bwa_align` processes.

Either [create](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#value) your `index_ch` as value channel, or keep the index out of a channel entirely and refer to it as a [parameter](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/config.html#scope-params).

Comment: Thanks for your response! I did as you suggested and used `Channel.value(params...)` for both my index and ref channels. While this did work I still seem to be missing something. While my `bwa_align` process is now aligning both sets of files, the `mapping_stats` still is 1 of 1. I was under the impression that any output from a process is a value channel, so this should work. Even more strange is this process only takes a single input. Do you have any advice for how to rectify this or what I am misunderstanding?

Comment: Afaik a process will only emit a value channel if ALL its input channels were value channels, otherwise it will be a queue chanel. Make a new question if you have a new question, it is hard to debug your new issue without the exact code. The output you show seems to suggest you are using the `-resume` option, maybe this is messing with the correct execution after you changed the flow.

Comment: Apologies, I was too impatient and responded prematurely. The executor updated to 2 of 2 for the `mapping_stats` following the completion of the second `bwa_align` process. Looks like everything is working as expected. Thanks again for your help!